# How to correctly update specific columns in an external database through an ECT?

Tags: external-content-type, bdc, bdc-model, external-data-column

Here is the scenario:

I have an External Content Type based on a specific table in an external DB.  The table itself has 33 columns, my ECT exposes a total of 13 of those columns, 7 as read-only and 6 as read/write.

I am *not* creating an External List based on my ECT, because I also want to have some other SharePoint columns on the list as well, and as far as my understanding goes, if you create an External List based on an ECT, you cannot add any other columns to it.

Therefore, I am adding the external data to a custom list by creating an External Data Column on my list and basing that on the ECT.

The problem now is that I can't seem to see how to update the 6 read/write columns.

If I add the external data column, and set the main column displayed as the identifier column, and then include all the other columns I want to show as "additional fields", there is no way to edit the fields I want editable in the UI, and if I go in with Powershell and look at those fields' `SchemaXML`, they are set to `ReadOnly="TRUE"`.

But then, if I add an external data column, and set the main column displayed as one of the columns I want editable, I can initially set the value of the field by choosing one of the external data rows in the picker, and it displays the correct value of that particular column.  But then if I go in to edit the item, and type something else into the field and try to save the item, I get an error:

> No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for
>   more options. You can also use Select button to choose External Data.

Which indicates to me that what's actually happening is that SharePoint is trying to *select a different external data row based on my new value*, rather than update the column (of the row which I had already selected) with my updated value.

If I go in with Powershell I can see that SharePoint has created a hidden note field called `MyECT_ID` that is connected to the external data column and contains an identifier that the BDC service uses to identify which row in the database the column should be showing data from.  So SP doesn't need the value of the display column to identify the external data row, it has another mechanism for that, and yet the behavior of updating the field is not to update the database, but to re-select something from the database.

So then... how can I set up external columns so that I can update the data in the database?

I'm at a bit of a loss at this point as to how that's actually supposed to work.

(This is in SP2013 on-prem, btw.)